# How can I create a PKG installer that can be installed on an external drive?

Tags: macos, applications, install, xcode, external-disk

I am trying to create a PKG installer with `pkgbuild` which lets the user decide if they want to put a part of the data to an external drive. I already did set the `customLocationAllowAlternateVolumes` to `True` in the Distribution.xml, but it is still not working. Why is that? Is there any restriction?

Comment: In general on MacOS you don't have an Installer. You put all the data and executable in the app and just copy that anywhere, If you need things that can be updated you create them on first run and if needed yuou can give the user a choice where to put them

Comment: I mean I am trying to create a PKG. So thats a kind of installer right?

Comment: Yes I know what a pkg is I was just pointing out that is not the usual way for macOS Applications

Comment: @mmmmmm We don't know that it's an application. Other things may need installing. Canonical instructions for making a PKG seem hard to come by.

Comment: For making a pkg - [Apple has docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution4/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004615-CH3-SW3) - of course now in archive like all useful docs - but I don't think they allow install across different volumes

Comment: @mmmmmm But they reference PackageMaker, which hasn't been in Xcode Additional Tools since 2012.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-macos-installer-packages-which-are-developer-id-ready but again no place to ask for a separate data directory

Comment: Is it something the installer needs to handle, or could it be a user decision the first time they run the application?